# how pass image using bundle from arraylist listview to detail activity

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity, bundle

I want to pass image from ArrayList into the detail activity, I'm using this code but the image is not load

**this is my MainActivty**

```
package com.example.latihanlist;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewStub;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewStub stubList;
    private ListView listview;
    private ListViewArrayAdapter listViewArrayAdapter;
    private List<Artikel> artikelList;

    private List<Artikel> getArtikelList() {
        artikelList= new ArrayList<>();
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 1","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 1"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 2","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 2"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 3","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 3"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 4","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 4"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 5","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 5"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 6","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 6"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 7","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 7"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 8","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 8"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 9","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 9"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 10","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 10"));
        return artikelList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stubList=(ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stublist);
        stubList.inflate();
        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        stubList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getArtikelList();
        listViewArrayAdapter=new
                ListViewArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,artikelList);
        listview.setAdapter(listViewArrayAdapter);



        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("data1", artikelList.get(position).getTitle().toString());
                bundle.putInt("data2", artikelList.get(position).getImageId());

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailBerita.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**this is my artikel class**

```
package com.example.latihanlist;

public class Artikel {
    private int imageId;
    private String title;
    private String timestamp;
    private String descriptions;

    public Artikel(int imageId, String title, String timestamp, String
            descriptions) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }
    **public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }**
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public String getDescriptions() {
        return descriptions;
    }
    public void setDescriptions(String descriptions) {
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }
}
```

**this is the detail activity class**

```
  package com.example.latihanlist;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    public class DetailBerita extends AppCompatActivity {

        ImageView mImageView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);

            TextView tvData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_title1);
            TextView tvData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
            mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            tvData2.setText(bundle.getString("data1"));
            mImageView .setImageResource(bundle.getInt("data2"));


        }

    }
```

**this is the detail layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/detail_title"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/detail_title1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I use ArrayList to show the data, and I set the image using int, and I'm trying to pass the data using bundle to the other activity. But it's only the data1 that showed in textView and the Imageview is not loaded. Please help me to correct this code.

Comment: Implement parceable in Artikel and send data as parceable instead of using bundle, and then you received complete model of Artikel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between mImageView and .setImageResource. Remove that and check it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to send array through parceable.. putParceableArray()

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

```
public class DetailBerita extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_view);

        TextView tvData1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_title1);
        TextView tvData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_title);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        tvData2.setText(bundle.getString("data1"));

        Drawable MyImageDrw = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,bundle.getInt("data2"));
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(MyImageDrw);



    }

}
```